# How is my Apache server auto-booting without a LaunchDaemon plist?

Tags: mojave, launchd, apache

A few months ago I setup an Apache server on a Mac Mini running Mac OS 10.14.6. It runs great. Each time I reboot the mac, the Apache service also starts, great.

My question is, why? There is no /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.x file. I can't find anything in the users Library as well. This is a clean install of the OS will nothing much else installed (except things like carbon copy cloner, bbedit, pathfinder, etc).

What am I missing?

Thanks,
dave

Comment: Have you tried checking `/Library/LaunchAgents/` and `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`?

Comment: Yes. The /Library/LaunchAgents/ only has four files (listed below) and the user home library (~/Library/) doesn't even have a LaunchAgents folder. I must be missing something.

Comment: There is a difference between `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`, which one did you check to see four files?

Comment: That's what I was missing. I forget there are three Libraries and not two and just assumed the root Library was the System/Library. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Apache is started through `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.apache.httpd</string>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>XPC_SERVICES_UNAVAILABLE</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY</key>
        <string>YES</string>
    </dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/httpd-wrapper</string>
        <string>-D</string>
        <string>FOREGROUND</string>
    </array>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Right. This file does not exist. There are only four files in that folder: com.apple.installer.x, com.barebones.x, com.bombich,x, com.cocoatech.x. The LaunchAgents folder is empty.

Comment: @DaveNasralla You're sure you check the right path? I count >300 files, a lot of them rather essential for basic macOS functionality.

Comment: Right. I got /Library confused with /System/Library. I'm good now.

Comment: @DaveNasralla Great, and welcome to AskDifferent. Please check out the [faq] for details about how the site works, and https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what your options are when people answer your posted questions.